# Get data from clientside (angular) to Node.js with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have a function in controller that should retrieve Google Maps coordinates from client and pass it to node.js, which will then save them to mongoose schema. However, nothing happens. Controller part looks like this:

```
    $scope.createEvent = function() {
        $http.post('/api/events', $scope.formData, $scope.latitude, $scope.longitude)
          .success(function (data) {
            var latitude = $scope.latitude;
            var longitude = $scope.longitude;
            $scope.formData = {};
            $scope.meetings = data;
            console.log(data);
         })
           .error(function(data) {
             console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

This part of map initialize function is responsible for getting coordinates

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
        $scope.latitude = event.latLng.lat();
        $scope.longitude = event.latLng.lng();
 });
```

Initialize function is also defined in the same controller as $scope.initialize

routes.js:

```
app.post('/api/events', function(req, res) {
    Event.create({
        title : req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
        latitude: req.body.latitude,
        longitude: req.body.longitude
    }, function(err, meeting) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Just in case, mongoose schema looks like this:

```
var eventsSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  longitude: String,
  latitude: String
});
```

Create action fires when user clicks on map, so latitude and longitude should be already known, but nothing happens. How can I send this information to node server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before posting U have to get that values into scope and then post to url... 
may be this values come from front end and bind that values to scope.

```
 $scope.createEvent = function() {
            $http.post('/api/events', {
            title : $scope.title,
            description: $scope.description
            latitude: $scope.latitude,
            longitude: $scope.longitude 
        })
              .success(function (data) {

                $scope.meetings = data;
                console.log(data);
             })
               .error(function(data) {
                 console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
```

I hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to create a factory service in your app
[angularJS.factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)
[angularJS.$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

```
app.factory('Events', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
 return $resource('/api/events', {}, 
     {
      create: {
       method: 'POST'
     }
     });
    }
   ]);
```

in your controller call facotory

```
app.controller('yourControllerName', ['$scope','Events'
function($scope,Events) {

$scope.createEvent = function(){
  var event = new Events({
        title : $scope.title,
        description: $scope.description
        latitude: $scope.latitude,
        longitude: $scope.longitude 
    });

    event.$create(function(data) {
     $scope.meetings = data;
     console.log(data);
    },function(err){
      console.log(err);
     });

}

 }
]);
```

I hope I helped!!